# Recursion with more parameters

Tags: haskell, recursion

I am trying to write an equivalent function to Javascript's "indexOf".(getting the index of a character in a string), but I am having problems when calling the recursive function.

This is the error:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `Int'
            with actual type `a0 -> [a0] -> Int'
In the return type of a call of `get_index'
Probable cause: `get_index' is applied to too few arguments
In the expression: get_index (index + 1 char str)
In an equation for `get_index':
    get_index index char str
      | index < 0 || index >= (length str) = - 1
      | (str !! index) == char = index
      | otherwise = get_index (index + 1 char str)
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This is my code:

```
index_of char str =
  get_index 0 char str

get_index index char str
  | index < 0 || index >= (length str) = -1
  | (str !! index) == char = index
  | otherwise = get_index(index + 1 char str)
```

First function's purpose is solely to call the recursion with the index parameter, nothing more, the problem I have is in the second function, the recursion.

Comment: Your mistake is in your recursive call to `get_index`. In the last line of `get_index`, you meant `get_index (index + 1) char str`, _not_ `get_index(index + 1 char str)`. And then the function works as expected!

Comment: Yes, it worked. Than you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it seems you're trying to use c-style function call syntax.
for a c-style function, e.g.

```c
// defining the function
int plus(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}

// elsewhere, calling the function
plus(a, b); // brackets surrounding only the arguments, comma separated
```

the equivalent Haskell code will be

```
-- defining the function
plus :: Int -> Int -> Int
plus a b = a + b

-- elsewhere, calling the function:
(plus a b) -- brackets surrounding the function and the arguments, no commas
-- note, plus (a b) would be equivalent to c: plus(a(b));
```

Note, these brackets are only ever needed for disambiguation, and in this case they can be removed, leaving `plus a b`.
In the following case, they would be needed:

```c
plus(a, times(b, c));
```

This becomes:

```
(plus a (times b c))
```

Which is the same as:

```
plus a (times b c)
```

However it is not the same as:

```
plus a times b c
```

Comment: I'd add that the outer parens are not required and should be omitted (this isn't Lisp!), unless `plus a b` is the argument to another function call.

Comment: I'll mention that they aren't necessary, but if this function is embedded in another function call then it is required for disambiguation, whereas no *additional* brackets are needed in this case in a c function call. Eg `f(x, g(y))` => `(f x (g y))` == `f x (g y)`, but not `f x g y`